# Getting master instead of main

Tags: github

When I use create-react-app and cd into the directory it already shows me (master) when I haven't even initialized git. When I try to do git init and set remote origin it still stays the same and my repository isn't connected. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Create react app initialises git automatically, and adds a .gitignore

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve it by this example

```
echo "# qqq" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com:{username}/{repository}.git
git push -u origin main
```